# How do I receive a third-party intent, and then act on it?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

My application relies on the intent `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` being fired, and so I set up a receiver in the manifest and I have a class that starts a service when it receives the intent.

However, when a user is using a lock-screen replacement app like WidgetLocker, the `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` intent may never be sent, or can be sent a bunch of times. (Once it was sent 5 times...)  WidgetLocker's website explains that the application *does* send its own intent for unlocking, `com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker.intent.UNLOCKED`.  In certain configurations of WidgetLocker, `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` may be fired before the user even unlocks the screen, so I was told that it would be best to set up a check for `com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker.intent.LOCKED`, and then wait to receive the `UNLOCKED` intent and do my work.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to set up a receiver for a third party intent.  I've added the actions to my receiver in the manifest just find, and I know that my broadcast receiver picks them up, but I need to filter them out.  Mainly, if I pick up the `LOCKED` intent, I want to ignore any `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` intents, and instead wait for the `UNLOCKED` intent, but I don't know how to wait for an intent upon receiving a different one.

Comment: "My application relies on the intent ACTION_USER_PRESENT being fired" -- I would try to eliminate this requirement.

Comment: Why's that?  The main feature of my app is toasting you as a reminder whenever you unlock your screen, so it's somewhat of a requirement...

Comment: Ah, sorry, nevermind. I was thinking `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` required an everlasting service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mainly, if I pick up the LOCKED intent, I want to ignore any ACTION_USER_PRESENT intents, and instead wait for the UNLOCKED intent, but I don't know how to wait for an intent upon receiving a different one.

Step #1: Create separate `BroadcastReceivers` for the WidgetLocker actions vs. `ACTION_USER_PRESENT`.

Step #2: Upon receipt of `LOCKED`, use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to disable your `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` receiver.

Step #3: Upon receipt of `UNLOCKED`, use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to re-enable your `ACTION_USER_PRESENT` receiver.

This could get a bit dicey in edge cases (e.g., user pops out the battery while `LOCKED`), but it's a starting point.

Comment: Why would I need separate receivers?  What's wrong with just one that picks up all three?

Comment: I mean, couldn't I just use something like: `if (intnet.getAction().equals(com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker.intent.LOCKED) { do stuff } else { do other stuff`

Comment: @PatrickMahoney: First, my enable/disable suggestion does not work with just one. Second, you would have to keep persisting your state somewhere, as your process may be terminated in between broadcasts.

Comment: But I have one last problem: Using `if(intent.getAction().equals(com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker.intent.LOCKED))`, Eclipse tells me that com.teslacoilsw cannot be resolved to a variable.  Is there a better way to check the intent?  And finally, how do I specify which receiver to disable in the manifest?  Thank you so much for your help @CommonsWare!

Comment: @PatrickMahoney: "Is there a better way to check the intent?" -- you need to use a literal string, which might be `"com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker.intent.LOCKED"` -- you'd have to ask them. "how do I specify which receiver to disable in the manifest?" -- by class (technically, via `ComponentName`) when calling [`setComponentEnabledSetting()`](http://goo.gl/xtf7I)